# windows does not honor routing table entries

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I'm trying to get to reason with Microsoft Windows 11 to respect the entries I create.

- First thing I noticed when using route ADD, is that well Windows keeps overriding metrics of entries I attempt to create. If I choose metric 1 for an entry it would end-up say 56. Why?
- Second:  In my situation I have two interfaces IF 12 which is WiFI and 267 which is an LTE adapter. I want traffic to keep flowing through 267 but only for  a specific destination 148.251.75.23.

While on Linux I would have accomplished this in 3 minutes, on Windows I'm struggling.

As you may see in the attached routing table the 148.251.75.23 has On-Link gateway which as I understand should make precedence even before processing of other routing table entries - it's On-Link. The netmask is 32 for this entry can't get more specific can it.

Already tried disabling default paths for the IF 12 Wifi device.

Folks my routing table is below.

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.17     12
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  178.182.233.210  PUBLIC_IP    267
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link     169.254.50.98    291
    169.254.50.98  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.50.98    291
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.50.98    291
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.1.17    268
     192.168.1.17  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.17    268
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.17    268
    192.168.222.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.222.1    291
    192.168.222.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.222.1    291
  192.168.222.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.222.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.17    268
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     169.254.50.98    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.222.1    291

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.17    268
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     169.254.50.98    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.222.1    291
```

After some mangling and dangling with Windows the following routing table is the closest to the desired thing I managed to arrive at (and still the route to achieving it was not driven through logic but through guessing - for instance by explicitly setting the priority of the LTE interface was I able to actually lower the priority of a path associated with it to be above the metric associated with the default gateway entry of the Wifi Interface) and guess what ? it still does not work.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.17     12
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0  178.182.233.210  PUBLIC_IP   266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    148.251.75.23  255.255.255.255  178.182.233.210  PUBLIC_IP     11
```

datagrams keep flowing through 192.168.1.17

The bottom line is that not only does the Microsoft's implementation totally neglect the 'choose best matching/closest path'paradigm in terms of netmask value entirely. But it also neglect the priority/metric assigned to a path. Not?

Allowing ourselves for some solid theory:

**The metric value determines the preference of a route, where a lower metric value indicates a more preferred route. In this case, the first route has a metric of 12, while the sixth route has a metric of 11. Since the sixth route has a lower metric, it should be the preferred route for packets destined to 148.251.75.23.**

Here, clearly it is not the case.

And then, one is unable to set the metric to whatever value one deems desirable because Microsoft Windows overrides. One needs to manipulate both the metric of the interface and the metric of the path to arrive at the desirable resulting value, which I wouldn't assume to be in line with any standard, not?

Comment: `On-link` here means the route is a *direct* route, I think, which would be inappropriate unless destination is e.g. in same the broadcast domain as the source. You should really add a route for `148.251.75.23` with the gateway being the same one as the default gateway of your LTE connection. (Just like you would in Linux.)

Comment: @TomYan Sure, the the point is, the 'On-Link' label (whatever it is) gets automatically added as a result of the following command "route ADD 148.251.75.23 MASK 255.255.255.255 PUBLIC_IP METRIC 1 IF 41" where PUBLIC_IP is an IP address assigned to the LTE interface. Needless to say, once I remove the default route for WiFi interface, everything starts flowing through IF 41(LTE) and yes, I've disabled default route processing for the WiFi interface.

Comment: I thought that the 'on-link' purpose is specifically to route through the 'on-link' assigned gateway, not? Well, if not then I proceeded explicitly as so "route ADD 148.251.75.23 MASK 255.255.255.255 178.182.233.210 METRIC 1 IF 41"  where 178.182.233.210 is the gateway address assigned to the interface. No luck either. The route is 100% omitted. And the default route of the Wifi Interface is being used. Welcome to Windows?

Comment: "On-link" means there is _no_ gateway at all (because the _destination itself_ is already on-link). For example, your subnet is on-link to you (by definition) so you never use some gateway to access it, while you use a gateway to access off-link destinations. But there are interface types for which there's no distinction.

Comment: @user1686 still, even with explicit path it does not work. See the example. Metric lowest in the entire routing table, explicit netmask /32 and still no luck. I would expect it to flow through the interface due to the lowest metric alone.. and due to the closets match in terms of the netmask value all by itself.

Comment: To be clear, metric determines the preference of a route _among otherwise equal routes_; the prefix length is the main criterion (/32 always wins over /0) and metric is only a tie-breaker. The route table as a whole is not sorted by metric. If Windows chooses a /0 over a /32, that's for some different reason (e.g. _source_ address match or explicit binding to an interface).

Comment: Well of course that is how I understood it. The closest path in terms of the prefix should be preferred and then the metric. Which is why I set the netmask value to /32. It doesn't cut it.

Comment: Just a random wild guess. Could Windows have some "smart", implicit override that it would avoid using a metered connection when there's a non-metered one? (Assuming the LTE connection is marked metered automatically or manually)

Comment: I gave up on this topic..